# How do I get the values from a certain form's inputs from a dynamically created table (with buttons) in HTML using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The below table is generated (from python/flask) in HTML (Edited - see below) using rows from a database. Each table row has it's own "Buy" and "Sell" button for each stock and ideally, when a user enters a number of shares to buy or sell in that row and clicks that row's button, it detects which button was pressed and gets the values of that form's inputs only (which will be stored in variables and posted down the "Buy" route). I'm just struggling on getting those values...

```
{% for row in tableData %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row.symbol }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.totalShares }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.price | usd }}</td>
        <td>{{ (row.totalShares * row.price) | usd }}</td>
        <td>
            <form id="portfolio-buy" class="needs-validation buy" novalidate action="/buy" method="post">
                <!--<input id="pf-buy-symbol" type="hidden" name="buy-symbol" value="{{ row.symbol }}"/>-->
                <input id="pf-buy-price" type="hidden" name="buy-price" value="{{ row.price }}"/>
                <input id="pf-buy-shares" class="form-control shares-buy-sell" type="number" min="1" max="{{ (cash / row.price) | round | int }}" placeholder="0" required />
                <button id="pf-btn-buy" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit">Buy</button>
            </form>

            <form id="portfolio-sell" class="needs-validation sell" novalidate action="/sell" method="post">
                <!--<input id="pf-sell-symbol" type="hidden" name="sell-symbol" value="{{ row.symbol }}"/>-->
                <input id="pf-sell-price" type="hidden" name="sell-price" value="{{ row.price }}"/>
                <input id="pf-sell-shares" class="form-control shares-buy-sell" type="number" min="1" max="{{ row.totalShares }}" placeholder="0" required />
                <button id="pf-btn-sell" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit">Sell</button>

            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I've thought of adding `"-{{ row.symbol }}"` to the IDs to distinguish them and use that to extract the info I need somehow but I have a hunch there is a much easier way that I'm missing.

After a lot of trial and error, this is the closest I got but this gives me all values, even the ones I don't want...

```
$("form#portfolio-buy :input").each(function(){
    var input = $(this);
    alert($(input).val());
});
```

P.S. I'm pretty new at this and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I've made progress with adding the `"-{{ row.symbol }}"` to the form (and extracting the "symbol" from that and therefore not needing the symbol input) and adding "buy" and "sell" to the classes but still having trouble getting the inputs.

```
var symbol = "";
var shares = 0;
var QuotePrice = 0;

var formsBuy = document.getElementsByClassName('buy');
// Loop over them and prevent submission
Array.prototype.filter.call(formsBuy, function(form)
{
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event)
    {
        // alert($(this).attr("id"));
        var formID = $(this).attr("id");
        symbol = formID.substr(14, formID.length - 14);
        $(this).each(function()
        {
            var input = $(this);
            alert($(input).val());
            switch($(input).attr("id"))
            {
                case "pf-buy-price":
                    quoteBuy = $(input).val();
                    break;
                case "pf-buy-shares":
                    shares = $(input).val();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
```

I can't seem to work out where I'm going wrong :(

Comment: Inspect the element and copy the select attributes of a specific div or element, and make sure you have the correct element id or class.

Comment: I couldn't figure out what you meant, sorry!

Comment: I was probably a little vague, but yes using developer tools in Chrome. I apologize for the lack of details.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I got that I needed to use the inspector in Chrome but couldn't work out how to apply it to my situation, sorry. I've never used it in that sense. Any idea on how I progress from here, syntax-wise?

Comment: I was able to mark an answer for you.

Comment: If your inputs in the form will be in the same order always, just grab them as an array and reference each item in order item[0] etc.

Comment: 1. [IDs must be unique in your HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), so you definitely need to add something to each `form` ID.  Your `input`s all have the same IDs too, so will not work. If you add the same the same `row.symbol` to the those as well, you can then identify them once you have the `symbol`, eg `$('#pf-buy-price-' + symbol)`.  Or get rid of the input IDs and use a class like `price`, and then you can find them like `$('#' + formID + ' .price')`.  Then you don't need the `.each` and `case` stuff.

Comment: 2. You are mixing plain JS and jQuery - probably simpler to stick to one, and if you are taking the performance hit in loading jQuery, you may as well use it.